# display 80 image in one figure all concatenating to each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to disply 80images in one figure with 10 columns and 8 rows, and all concatenating to each other from both vertically and horizontally using python

this output expected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QCod.jpg)

and this my code trying to apply this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import os
from PIL import Image

# Specify the path to the folder containing the images
image_folder = '/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/Speaker_image.fld'

# Get a list of image file names in the folder
image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(image_folder) if f.endswith('.png')]

# Create a 10x8 grid using gridspec
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 20))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(8, 10)

# Initialize an index to keep track of the current image
index = 0

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(10):
        if index < len(image_files):
            image_path = os.path.join(image_folder, image_files[index])
            img = Image.open(image_path)
            img = img.resize((50, 50))  # Resize the image to 50x50 pixels

            ax = plt.subplot(gs[i, j])
            ax.imshow(img)
            ax.axis('off')  # Turn off the axis labels
            index += 1

# Remove space between subplots (both vertically and horizontally)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

plt.show()
```

Thank for help

Answer (score 0):

Two options i can think of:

1. use plt.subplots directly:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

from PIL import Image

image_folder = "/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/Speaker_image.fld"
n_row = 8
n_col = 10
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_row, n_col, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(n_col, n_row))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)


image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(image_folder) if f.endswith(".png")][
    : n_row * n_col
]

for ax, file in zip(axes.flatten(), image_files):
    image_path = os.path.join(image_folder, file)
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    img = img.resize((50, 50))
    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

However, this still leaves some small gaps (for reasons unknown to me)
[image]

Two fully avoid those gaps you can

2. [concatenate the images](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-concat-images/) before plotting them

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

from PIL import Image

image_folder = "/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/Speaker_image.fld"
n_row = 8
n_col = 10

image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(image_folder) if f.endswith(".png")][
    : n_row * n_col
]


def get_concat_h(im1, im2):
    if im1 is None:
        return im2
    dst = Image.new("RGB", (im1.width + im2.width, im1.height))
    dst.paste(im1, (0, 0))
    dst.paste(im2, (im1.width, 0))
    return dst


def get_concat_v(im1, im2):
    if im1 is None:
        return im2
    dst = Image.new("RGB", (im1.width, im1.height + im2.height))
    dst.paste(im1, (0, 0))
    dst.paste(im2, (0, im1.height))
    return dst

super_row = None
super_image = None

for i_row in range(n_row):
    for i_col in range(n_col):
        file = image_files[i_col * i_row + i_row * n_col]
        image_path = os.path.join(image_folder, file)
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        img = img.resize((50, 50))
        super_row = get_concat_h(super_row, img)
    super_image = get_concat_v(super_image, super_row)
    super_row = None

plt.imshow(super_image)
plt.show()
```